# Is there a difference in these two state update methods?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently playing around with the state by trying to update it.
I came across two solutions to achieve my update as you can see from my 2 Examples.

**I was wondering if there are any major differences between these two approaches ?**

Because in the End you always ending up, updating the State. But I'm also curious from a performance / architecture point of view.

While I think the first Example is cleaner and clearer to understand then the second one, I don't really know if the "cleaner" aspect is really true.

###### Example 1

```
      const handleTableRowEdit = (row) => {
            // Get current Items State
            // Spread all elements from array into new array.
            const existingItems = [...items];

            // Add new Property to passed row object
            const newRow = { ...row, isEditing: true };

            // Find Array Index from passed row
            const findIndex = items.findIndex((x) => x.id === newRow.id);

            // Update Array with new Row at index position
            existingItems[findIndex] = { ...newRow };

            // Set State to updated Array.
            setItems(existingItems);
        };
```

###### Difference Highlighting

```
        ...
        
        // Spread all elements from array into new array.
        const existingItems = [...items];
        ...

         // Set State to updated Array.
         setItems(existingItems);
```

###### Example 2

```
      const handleTableRowEdit = (row) => {
            // Get current Items State
            // Set reference to existing items Array.
            const existingItems = items;
            
            // Add new Property to passed row object
            const newRow = { ...row, isEditing: true };
            
            // Find Array Index from passed row
            const findIndex = items.findIndex((x) => x.id === newRow.id);

            // Update Array with new Row at index position
            existingItems[findIndex] = { ...newRow };

            // Set State to updated Array.
            // Set new State by spreading all elements of existing array into a new array.
            setItems([...existingItems]);
        };
```

###### Difference Highlighting

```
        ...
        
        // Set reference to existing items Array.
        const existingItems = items;
        ...

         // Set new State by spreading all elements of existing array into 
         a new array.
         setItems([...existingItems]);
```

Comment: The second one mutates the previous state. Don't do that.

Comment: @Bergi Ohh I see, you mean because in the second one I'm always referring to the same object / array reference ?  And this is indeed the equivalent of saying `items = XYZ`

Comment: @K.Kröger yes, you ultimately want an immutable state which is passed in pure functions, functions that don't have side-effects like setting values to the previous state's object reference like your first example.